# Latex Not Formatted

Tags: bug, mathjax, formatting, google-chrome

I get the following error when trying to view formatted questions in Chrome 45 on Windows 7.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

for http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/config/TeX-AMS_HTML-full.js?rev=2.5.3

It possible that mathjax prevents sites from linking to it directly from another site?

[image: Here is an image.]

Comment: Does it happen for all questions containing MathJax? Could you add a screenshot?

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes all screen shot added.

Comment: If this only happens to you in chrome and not in other browsers, you should probably add ([meta-tag:google-chrome]) tag. I hope somebody more knowledgeable than me comes with some good advice how to solve this.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266305/latex-not-formatted

Comment: Does any of the things suggested in older post like [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10776/mathjax-not-working) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6198/no-latex-rendering-at-all) help with your problem? (They mainly mention https in those posts.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I think they are related but if you look at the picture I am not loading the https version of the site.

Comment: Here is a temporary workaround https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tex-renderer/enfbnhdcmcipeoakalehejknkpbajodp?hl=en